# Concatenation doesn't seem to work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation

I am doing something like this in my application. I have sequence of Id values like ID1, ID2 etc. I am trying to fetch the ID value using for loop.

Concatenation doesn't seem to work.

```js
function Save(count,Id1,Id2,Id3){
  var response = [];
  for(var i=1;i <= count; i++) {
    value = `${'Id' + i}`;
    alert(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Save(3,1,2,3)" />
```

Comment: Am I missing something or does your example work fine?

Comment: @j08691 It displays the argument names `Id1`, `Id2`, ... but he wants to display the argument values `1`, `2`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a String `"Id1"`, you cannot interpolate a variable name. But with ES6, you can use the [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) (`...`) to convert parts of your arguments to an Array:

```js
function Save(count, ...ids) {
  var response = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    value = ids[i];
    alert(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Save(3,1,2,3)" />
```

Before ES6, you would have to use `arguments` (that would convert **all** arguments):

```js
function Save() {
  var response = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= arguments[0]; i++) {
    value = arguments[i];
    alert(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Save(3,1,2,3)" />
```

Or use `eval`, but don't. This is just for the example:

```js
function Save(count, Id1, Id2, Id3, Id4) {
  var response = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    value = eval(`Id${i}`);
    alert(value);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Save(3,1,2,3)" />
```

Comment: This is [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters). If you call `Save(..anArray)`, then it's called [*spreading*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Nice one! Most elegant I think.

Comment: [Spread is for *expanding*, rest is for *collecting*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Rest_syntax_parameters).

Answer (score 0):

That doens't works because will throw a syntax exception. Its not the way you use interpolation. There are lots of ways to do what you need in a simple way:

- Using an array:

```js
function Save(ids) {
  var response = [];
  for(var i=0;i < ids.length; i++) {
    value = ids[i];
    console.log(value);
  }
}

Save([1,2,3,4]);
```

- Using `arguments` constant:

```js
function Save(){
  var response = [];
  for(var i=0;i < arguments.length; i++) {
    value = arguments[i];
    console.log(value);
  }
}

Save(1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: for the code using `arguments` object, you're getting `undefined` at the end because in the loop you set `i <= arguments.length` which will have an additional undefined argument. You'll need to set the stopping condition to `i < arguments.length` for example or maybe `i <= arguments.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how interpolation works. It just inserts the value of the expression into a string. For example:

```js
const age = 30
console.log(`I am ${age} years old!`) // Prints "I am 30 years old"
```

It doesn't interpret a string as an expression, which is what you apparently want to do. You *could* do that using `eval`, but this is most likely a step into the wrong direction.

If you want to iterate over the given values, just use an array instead:

```js
function save (values) {
  for (const value of values) {
    alert(value)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="save([9, 8, 7])" />
```

You can also iterate manually over the indexes, that can be useful if you need the index too, for example:

```js
function save (values) {
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    alert(`Index ${i} = ${values[i]}`)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="save([9, 8, 7])" />
```

Or, if you want to keep your method of calling the function with multiple arguments (although the `count` argument is completely unnecessary), you can destructure the arguments into an array, like this:

```js
function save (...values) {
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    alert(`Index ${i} = ${values[i]}`)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="save(9, 8, 7)" />
```

If you really wanted that `count` argument there, you could use `function save (count, ...values)`. As a side note, there is also `arguments`, which is an array-like object that holds all the arguments passed to your current function, so you could iterate over that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. using Array, fixed my issue